# How to make URL alias

Tags: alias, svn, url

I am using `subversuin` to manage my project files. One thing is annoying for me. Every time I want to check out my repo I need to use `"svn co "URL_TO_MY_REPOSITORY"` command. The ULR is very long. I have tried to make alias of this url using 
`alias repo='MY_URL'` command. Unfortunetly it does not work.

The `svn co repo` command returned this error: svn: `E205000: Error parsing arguments`

Is there any way to make alias of URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias is a short cut for a command , but what you want is a variable.

Add this to ~/.bashrc

```
export repo='your_url'
```

Then source your .bashrc or log into a new terminal and run

```
svn co $repo
```

For additional information see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Basically an alias is a full command and you are using it as a variable.

You could of course write an alias or a function

```
alias mysvn='svn co your_repo'
```

You would then run

```
mysvn
```

but it is likely a variable is more in line with what you want.